# Apply functions to specific DataFrame columns, and keep the remaining columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we have the following pandas DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
    'Value': [1, 2, 3],
    'Duration': ['1s', '2s', '3s'],
})
```

Now, say I want to transform the `Name` and `Value` columns, but not the `Duration` column. Is there a DataFrame method like `pd.DataFrame.apply` or `pd.DataFrame.transform` that will apply functions to these columns specifically, while keeping the remaining columns? Something like:

```py
df = df.some_method({
  'Name': lambda name: name.upper(),
  'Value': lambda value: value + 1
})
```

Currently, I'm only aware of the following method of doing that:

```py
df[['Name', 'Value']] = df.apply({
  'Name': lambda name: name.upper(),
  'Value': lambda value: value + 1
}, axis='columns')
```

This is unergonomic if I need to update, say, 10+ columns at a time, and list out every column in the `apply()` call and the assignment.

Comment: Why not `df["Name"] = df["Name"].str.upper();df["Value"] += 1` ?

Comment: If you want to do it one command, you can do `df = df.eval("Name = Name.str.upper()\nValue = Value + 1")`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), which will overwrite existing columns as well as create new ones:

```
df = df.assign(
    Name=df['Name'].str.upper(),
    Value=df['Value']+1
)
```

Output for your sample data:

```
  Name  Value Duration
0  FOO      2       1s
1  BAR      3       2s
2  BAZ      4       3s
```